# combination of jsonarray and jsonobject parsing using retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

[{"location":"Pune","nid":"3","title":"Internatinal dance academy","field_product_images":[{"fid":"36","uid":"1","filename":"a.jpg","uri":"public://a.jpg","filemime":"image/jpeg","filesize":"72172","status":"1","timestamp":"1482923103","rdf_mapping":[],"alt":"","title":"","width":"200","height":"150"}],"field_timing":"8:00am-3.00pm","field_location":"2nd mzin road 7th block"},{"location":"Delhi","nid":"2","title":"Yamaha Balle Classes","field_product_images":[{"fid":"169","uid":"1","filename":"dance_music_people_traffic_54208_1920x1080.jpg","uri":"public://dance_music_people_traffic_54208_1920x1080.jpg","filemime":"image/jpeg","filesize":"5850","status":"1","timestamp":"1495020629","rdf_mapping":[],"alt":"","title":"","width":"200","height":"150"}],"field_timing":"10.00am-4.30pm","field_location":"jaynagar 4th block"}]

[this is my json url](http://iwizkidtest.goalsr.com/iwizkidstaging/expose/featured)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is your issue, Please state your problem clearly

Comment: Ask question properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay [goto](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

paste your json>onRight Side select Source type:>JSON and Annotation style:>GSON

this is creating your Model class as response.

Now visit [Here to use retrofit](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

now your can easily deal with any JSON data